Jest/Typescript: Even with multiple test files and maxWorkers=4 its not running with parallelism on a 8 core CPU
I'm trying to find the reason why my test suites are not executed in parallel even if i'm using multiple test suite files, the configuration maxWorkers=4 on an 8 CORE CPU, using Typescript and Jest (v29.7.0)...
What am I missing?
I've check all different options and the one I came up with was this:
jest --no-cache --passWithNoTests --maxWorkers=4 --testPathPattern=tests/*"

How did you know your test suites are not executed in parallel?

from the default reporter pushing info on console, i see the different test suites called one after the other one....
